# Does Power Automate work with SharePoint Online with active ip filters?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

Background: My corporation restricts access for certain networks on SharePoint Online. This is not negotiable and a security mechanism we want to employ. We know that there are some scenarios where data can still be exposed through other networks, but the threat is negligible to us.

A few months ago our Power Automate workflows began to fail specifically on getting user account information (Get user profile (V2)) with an error that corporate policies disallow access on this ressource. If the SharePoint IP-Filter is deactivated, the flows run without error.

There is some documentation about which Azure and SharePoint IPs need to be whitelisted, but it still doesn't work. The field where you can specify networks to be whitelisted is limited to 5000 characters, so I needed to use CIDR notations and expand the ranges a bit, especially on IP6 adresses. But the needed IP wasn't among those. You can also fill in 0.0.0.0/0 which results in the flows working again, so a missing IP is very likely.

Has anyone encountered similar problems and has a solution? We are currently porting back to Workflows 2013, but I fear they will deprecated too at some point. I know that IP whitelists aren't the prefered mechanism to restrict access, but it currently is our only option because manpower is quite limited.

Sorry for the long text and I would appreciate any input.